how to build the binaries in ffmpeg-kit
hey I want to use the ffmpeg in my android app and I used the ffmpeg-kit
In the README of the ffmpeg-kit for android they write the steps to create binary but I'm facing difficulty understanding thest steps

First is -> to setup android SDK or NDK i have checked these in my Android studio and I also added these in my environment variables

Second -> is to install different packages autoconf automake libtool pkg-config curl git doxygen nasm cmake gcc gperf texinfo yasm bison autogen wget autopoint meson ninja ragel groff gtk-doc-tools libtasn1 im using windows so i installed window's one other is for the linux

third -> is to run a android.sh command in the root directory of the project this will generate the binary for different architectures


This is what is understant after reading the doc
i dont understand the android.sh command from where can i get these script file , do i need to add .aar from here
or do I need to copy the whole repository, i tried  adding .arr file to my libs folder and trying to implement it inside my dependency but it showed error that duplicates classes
If anyone used this library please tell me how can i implement and build binary
